# Why is the df for the χ² test of independence (r − 1)(c − 1)?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I understanding that if Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub>, …, Z<sub>k</sub>, are independent standard normal variables, then Z<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + Z<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + … + Z<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup> has a χ² distribution with k degrees of freedom.

However, say we have a 2 rows and 3 columns, then we're taking (observed - expected)<sup>2</sup> divided by expected for 6 cells. Why then is the degrees of freedom not 6?

Comment: Very general answers, covering a range of points of view and degrees of sophistication, can be found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921.